# How to deploy from bitbucket to a server without Shell access and without git

Tags: git, shell

I have a repository on bitbucket. I wanna to deploy to a server from bitbucket but on the servwer I've no access to the shell. All what I have is a simple Cpanel, don't even know if git is present.
So how could I deploy my commits directly on the live server without git and a linux shell ?

Is there a simple way?

Comment: How much control do you have over this server?  Can you install stuff on it?

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of tools out there that let you achieve this

Here are three I know of from the top of my hat: [DeployHQ](http://www.deployhq.com), [FTPloy](http://ftploy.com), dploy.io

All of these have a free plan that can accomodate you if you only have a single project, otherwise it'll set you back about 15$/month.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to deploy, you could set up a php script that fetches the content of the repository "by hand" and copies it's files to certain directory on your server. Then, you put some kind of hook in your repository that calls that php script.

It's really awful to do this, but it's a hacky way to get it.